# Can I make my nether tunnel work in unloaded chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm working on a nether tunnel which allows you to travel by minecart as well as by ice road by having pistons extend and retract:

**Minecart mode:**
[image]

**Ice road mode:**
[image]

I've got 2 stations at the beginning and the end of the tunnel where I can see if the player walks or takes the minecart by having the tunnel in ice road mode unless the player uses a button to call the minecart at the station.

However redstone does not work inside chunks that are not loaded by the game. Therefor I cannot use this for really long tunnels (which is something I would like to do though)

Is there a way arround that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [detector rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Detector_Rail) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Detector_Rail&oldid=1251964)).

Replace a normal rail with it, take the redstone signal from it and use that to transform the next part of the tunnel into minecart mode. Then, after a short delay (long enough to let you drive through), transform it back.

Apart from that, is there any advantage in having the tunnel in minecart mode? How I see it, you could just permanently leave it in ice road mode, it can still be used with a minecart.

Comment: Minecart mode is for looks. It's really claustrofobic in ice road mode.

Comment: The detector rail might work for that but then I need to make itso it changes the blocks ahead of it so it does not look wierd... I'll figure that one out...